# Distributed checksum generation

Tags: ruby, redis, md5

I have a service that runs over HTTP and takes file chunks (usually 10MB) and stores them as chunks on a remote file system. The combination of these chunks would make up a complete file.

I would like to generate some metadata about the file from the chunks. Specifically I would like to generate the total file size and MD5 checksum for the file.

The end file can be relatively large (500+ MBytes). Is there a way to iterative generate the checksum in a distributed manner? For example lets say I have two web server running this service behind a load balancer that distributes the requests between the two servers. Is it possible to generate the MD5 checksum for the complete file on the fly using something like a shared Redis server?

I am trying to avoid caching the chunks locally on disk or querying the remote data store for the actual file contents after they have fully been uploaded.

Comment: What are you *really* trying to achieve here, and with what security guarantees? It can't be time savings; it takes an average of only **1.323 seconds** of wall time to calculate the MD5 for a 512-MiB file on my laptop; server-class hardware should be more performant.

Comment: It's not a time thing, the file being in chunks is a property of the services I was building and not something I was doing specifically for this.

Answer (score 3):

You can do this with a [Merkle Tree](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Merkle_tree), [like Cassandra](http://wiki.apache.org/cassandra/AntiEntropy).

Quoting from Amazon's Dynamo section 4.7,

> To detect the inconsistencies between replicas faster and to minimize the amount of transferred data, Dynamo uses Merkle trees. A Merkle tree is a hash tree where leaves are hashes of the values of individual keys. Parent nodes higher in the tree are hashes of their respective children. The principal advantage of Merkle tree is that each branch of the tree can be checked independently without requiring nodes to download the entire [...] data set.

Comment: Good suggestion, but there are security implications to generating the *top hash* from a collection of independently-calculated leaves. You might also want to link the definition of a [Merkle tree](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Merkle_tree) into your answer for the benefit of future visitors.

Answer (score 0):

Found this little gem. It allows you to accumulatively calculate an MD5 sum using a database.

https://github.com/jarl-dk/digest_extensions